# Android Studio Reinstall - INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE Thereafter

Tags: android, debugging

I had to do an Android Studio complete reinstall due to a corrupted gradle update download failure. So I uninstalled completely (removing all keystores in the installation folder if there were any there) and did a reinstall with the newer Giraffe version.

Since then I have had no end of problems.

I have a program folder that worked. Now when I debug it says:

```
Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE
```

and also

```
Application Installation Failed
The device already has an application with the same package but a different signature.
In order to proceed, you will have to uninstall the existing application.
```

Basically it needs to uninstall the old app on my android-phone and needs to reinstall the new one saying there is an incompatibility in the versions.

On another app which worked the other day with the new Giraffe install. It now will not connect the debugger to the phone-app and I have to do a Forced-Close on the half open app on my phone.

However, with that app I can get it running using the no-debug option for running an app inside the android studio.

When I try to run with the debugger, the log says:

```
E  ANR in com.myapp.www.myapp, time=12753387
Reason: executing service com.myapp.www.myapp/com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.JobInfoSchedulerService
Load: 7.12 / 5.94 / 5.61
Android time :[2023-12-13 20:06:01.26] [12755.629]
CPU usage from 116718ms to 0ms ago (2023-12-13 20:04:02.305 to 2023-12-13 20:05:59.022):
14% 926/system_server: 10% user + 4.3% kernel / faults: 20097 minor 1 major
4.7% 1310/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 3.3% user + 1.3% kernel / faults: 4483 minor 22 major
2.7% 239/surfaceflinger: 1.3% user + 1.4% kernel / faults: 1009 minor
2.4% 360/adbd: 0.5% user + 1.8% kernel / faults: 10212 minor
1.5% 163/mmcqd/0: 0% user + 1.5% kernel
1.8% 1091/com.android.systemui: 1.2% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 2330 minor 9 major
1.6% 6435/com.android.vending: 1.3% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 10969 minor 18 major
1.5% 211/logd: 0.4% user + 1% kernel / faults: 185 minor
1.3% 5646/com.google.android.gms: 1% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 7934 minor 5 major
1.2% 13277/kworker/0:2: 0% user + 1.2% kernel
1.1% 13229/kworker/0:1: 0% user + 1.1% kernel
1% 11537/logcat: 0.5% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 1 minor
0.6% 104/frame_update_wo: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
0.6% 11546/process-tracker: 0.1% user + 0.4% kernel / faults: 8 minor
0.5% 9946/process-tracker: 0.1% user + 0.4% kernel / faults: 16 minor
0.3% 103/present_fence_w: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
0.3% 1882/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search: 0.2% user + 0% kernel / faults: 6251 minor
0.3% 1340/com.android.phone: 0.3% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1051 minor
0.3% 91/hps_main: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
0.2% 1574/com.android.bluetooth: 0% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 35 minor
0.2% 13038/kworker/u9:0: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
0% 1769/com.archos.launcher: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 4020 minor
0.2% 13083/kworker/u9:1: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
0.2% 233/mtkmal: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2 minor
0.1% 273/zygote: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 2549 minor
0.2% 7/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
0.2% 2653/com.google.android.ims: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 283 minor
0.1% 1274/tx_thread: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
0.1% 188/jbd2/mmcblk0p22: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
0.1% 155/bat_thread_kthr: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
0% 70/kswapd0: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                          0.1% 56/cfinteractive: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                                                                          0% 238/servicemanager: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
                                                                                                          0.1% 9923/transport: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 39 minor
                                                                                                          0% 237/lmkd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 13 minor
                                                                                                          0% 12725/installer: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 392 minor
                                                                                                          0% 697/gsm0710muxd: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                          0% 89/pbm: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                          0% 156/mtk charger_hv_: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                          0% 282/mediaserver: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 5 minor
                                                                                                          0% 1329/wpa_supplicant: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                          0% 13197/kworker/u8:1: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                          0% 878/mtkrild: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                          0% 1650/com.google.process.gapps: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 614 minor
                                                                                                          0% 277/installd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 50 minor
                                                                                                          0% 946/rilproxy: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
                                                                                                          0% 1714/com.cs.fingerprint: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 563 minor
                                                                                                          0% 1594/ged_srv: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                          0% 9228/kworker/u8:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                          0% 57/ion_mm_heap: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                          0% 106/display_idle_de: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                          0% 1090/sdcard: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 33 minor
                                                                                                          0% 13/kworker/1:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                          0% 17/kworker/2:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                          0% 101/display_esd_che: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                          0% 283/netd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 119 minor
                                                                                                          0% 9321/com.android.defcontainer: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1583 minor
                                                                                                          0% 10/migration/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                          0% 262/thermal: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                          0% 274/audioserver: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 49 minor
                                                                                                          0% 12112/kworker/u8:3: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                          0% 11/migration/1: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                          0% 21/kworker/3:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                          0% 123/btif_rxd: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                          0% 1355/com.mediatek.wfo.impl: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 26
```

Comment: `needs to reinstall the new one saying there is an incompatibility in the versions`...it's not the version it's the signature of the package. What key did you sign the previous install with? It's different than what you're using now.

Comment: I have all my passcodes etc. But how do I put these in when I am just at the debugging stage? and not the install the package to Google Play stage?

Comment: Was the app installed built in debug or release? Does your gradle file specify a keystore to use? As an example, my main project uses a keystore defined in `build.gradle` for release builds, otherwise it uses the debug keystore which is on `$HOME/.android/` on my mac.